# Why French characters don't work using utf-8 with Java?

Tags: java, html, file-io, utf-8, character

I have a HTML file with some French character in it. I need to replace some string inside that file, so I do the following:

```
public static void replaceStringInFile(String filePath, String oldText, String newText)
{
    try
    {
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.replace(oldText, newText);
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My strings are replaced, but the French character are not there, replaced with ï¿½

If I replace UTF_8 with ISO_8859_1, it's working.

I thought UTF_8 was universal? Should work with French? I tried to specify utf-8 in the html file header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
....
</style>
```

I would like to understand why UTF_8 isn't keeping my French characters...

Comment: Try the html5 doc type declaration  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I think you're right. I'll keep html4 but that explains why I need ISO_8859_1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to know the encoding of the text file before you read it. Apparently, it is originally an HTML file without meta charset.

You guessed UTF-8. It's not UTF-8 because reading it detected bytes that don't correspond to UTF-8 and therefore were replaced with the Unicode replacement character [U+FFFD �](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which you are then displaying(?) using the incorrect encoding, turning � into the Mojibake "ï¿½".

So, you'd have to go back to the sender/writer to find out what the encoding is. Then you can write a program to read it.

Comment: If you want to continue guessing, ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252 and CP850 are possibly good ones.

Comment: I am facing a similar situation. My source is JSON and file is saved as UTF-8. But when I read and display in UI, it's a mess. But if I keep the file in UTF-8 BOM it works like a charm. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not that utf-8 is not working with Java.
The problem is your file is not utf-8.
To confirm that you can run `"file -I your_file_path"`: if your output is something like `"your_file_name:text/plain; charset=unknown-'somenumber'bit"` that means it is not utf-8.